# Linux SVN recover files

Tags: linux, svn, data-recovery

A recent update over unversioned directories removed a bunch of files. Is there a way I can manually recover these lost files?

P.S. I cannot recover them from subversion, as the files I am looking for were never committed to SVN control. I have looked in the linux trash folder, which only contains files which have been manually deleted.

edit: Actually, the files were lost through an accidental svn rm operation. Unfortunately I cannot use revert as the files I am trying to recover were newly created and not under version control yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If files were lost during a `svn update` operation, there's not a lot you can do.  I would suggest looking for hidden backup files that your editor may have created (in the directory where the file originally was or in the editor's temporary directory).

If you remember the name of one of the files, you can try using `find` to see if there's a backup copy of it somewhere on the disk.

Comment: Actually, they were lost through an accidental svn rm operation. Unfortunately I cannot use revert as the files I am trying to recover were newly created and not under version control yet.

Comment: @whamsicore- If you used `svn rm` without the `--force` option, it should not have removed unversioned files or folders.  Regardless, Subversion's delete command doesn't back up files before it deletes them.  Unless another program (like an editor) has a temporary copy cached somewhere, your files are most likely lost.